# extract line from same string

Tags: string, table

I have a table like this:

[image]

and a file containing 2 string from the third column as:
apple
potato

i would like to extract the header and all the line that contain the string apple and potato to obtain this

[image]

thanks

Comment: What format for the table? jpeg files like in your question?

Comment: its a txt table

Comment: Post the text instead of posting an image.

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk`:

```
awk 'FNR == 1 || /potato|apple/'
```

Using `sed`:

```
sed -n '1p; /potato\|apple/p'
```

In both cases, line number 1 and any lines matching `potato|apple` are printed.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the txt table again in plain text:

```
A       B       C       D       E
21      63      apple   yellow  5
23      69      lemon   green   6
45      135     orange  yellow  7
67      201     mango   green   4
54      162     potato  maroon  5
```

Though I could think of a solution with low complexity, I think it is a bit hackish :-)
Supposing the table txt file is called `table1`

```
$ head -1 table1 && grep '\b\(potato\|apple\)\b' table1
```

This will take the first line and append the `grep` result to it. `\b` is a word boundary. So this will ensure that words like "grapple (hook)" are filtered out :)
Another more complex solution will assume that A,B,C... are separated by tabulators `\t`:

```
$ grep '\(\b\(potato\|apple\)\b\|\([A-Z]\|\(\t\|\n?$\)\)\)' table1
```

Comment: sorry the table is tab delimited and i cannot write potato and apple because i have a file with the list of string to excract from the table

Comment: @IlarioFerrocino In that case use `head -1` and `grep -Ff name-of-file-with-strings`.

Comment: @IlarioFerrocino The more complex solution (2nd line) does take tabulators into account.

Comment: Hi Muru does not working